# Error with FirebaseUI RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am getting this error while running an app.I have posted my code below.

```
09-23 15:40:02.995 23658-23677/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzro.zzg
09-23 15:40:05.985 23658-23694/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5d26e508 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5e497a40 arg=0x0
09-23 15:40:05.986 23658-23696/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5d26e328 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5e597a40 arg=0x0
09-23 15:40:05.987 23658-23694/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5d26e508 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=DHE_RSA
09-23 15:40:05.988 23658-23696/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5d26e328 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=DHE_RSA
09-23 15:40:08.181 23658-23742/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5ec91e38 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5e497ab0 arg=0x0
09-23 15:40:08.184 23658-23742/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5ec91e38 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
09-23 15:40:12.161 23658-23658/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/test: Exception
09-23 15:40:12.170 23658-23658/com.cleanpune.android.cleanpuneproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: details
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzst(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:154)
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                                            at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:183)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1482)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:147)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:294)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:547)
                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I dont know where am I going wrong.Kindly Help please!
I am included all the libraries and am usinhg picasao for retrieving images.
Here is the TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> mAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.posts_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));






}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.posts_row,
            PostViewHolder.class,
            databaseReference

    )
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setDetails(model.getDetails());
            viewHolder.setLocation(model.getLocation());
            viewHolder.setImages(getApplicationContext(),model.getImages());


        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View view;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;

    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_location);
        textView.setText(location);
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_location);
        textView.setText(details);
    }

    public void setImages(Context context, String images) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.with(context).load(images).into(image);

    }
 }

}
```

Here is the Model Post class

```
public class Post {
public String Details, Location, Images;

public Post(String details, String location) {
    Details = details;
    Location = location;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return Details;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return Location;
}
public Post(){

}

public String getImages() {
    return Images;
}
```

}

Comment: kindly share your model class to

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your code that confuse the Firebase client:

1. your fields are public, but you also have getters/setters
2. your fields names start with a uppercase letter

If you change your class to be more idiomatic, it looks like

```
public class Post {    
    private String details, location, images;

    public Post(){ }
    public Post(String details, String location) {
        this.details = details;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can have a class with only public fields (and no getters/setters):

```
public class Post {    
    public String Details, Location, Images;

    public Post(){ }
    public Post(String details, String location) {
        Details = details;
        Location = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions,but did'nt work.

Comment: That sounds weird. Can you update your question to show the new code. IT would also be nice if you could reduce the code to the [minimum needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example: you likely get the same problem with only the `details` property and even without FirebaseUI (by simply calling `snapshot.getValue(Post.class)`)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try using this model class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Post {
    public String Details, Location, Images;

    public Post(){

    }

    public Post(String details, String location, String images) {
        Details = details;
        Location = location;
        Images = images;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("Details", Details);
        result.put("Location", Location);
        result.put("Images", Images);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: what should be my change in the TestActivity

Comment: No changes in test activity

Comment: It's not worked out still.An app is crashing after successful uploading when it goes to main activity.It waits for a while and crashes